# Calculate Amount in Microsoft Excel according to Date

Tags: excel, vba

I have written my expenses for 7 months. I want to know my monthly expense sum as on 5th of every month. How should I do that in excel?

Detailed: Expenses are written roughly on everyday basis. And I can calculate the sum total of all the expenses till date. Now I want to create a checkpoint or say the monthly expense.
Format:

```
S. No. | Date | Particulars | Amount
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for VBA with this.

If you have XL 2007 (2010) and Analysis ToolPak available as an add-in, you can use this.

Say your columns are in A:D, with row 1 hold column headings.

Place your monthly dates down column F, starting in F2

```
1/5/2012
2/5/2012
3/5/2012
```

Then in G2, write this formula:

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$37,$B$2:$B$37,"<="&F2,$B$2:$B$37,">"&EDATE(F2,-1))
'adjust $37 to fit your specific row number where your data ends
```

Then fill that down against your dates. You will have monthly sums from the 6th of the previous month to the 5th of the given month.

If you need a slight adjustment, let me know, but this should really get you started on the right path.

Lastly, if you are on different version of XL or don't have ToolPak, let me know and I can adjust the formulas to work with you.